# How to add a flat amount to an order. Using Drupal commerce module

Tags: commerce

I need to add a flat amount to an order using the http://drupal.org/project/commerce module.

Lets say I have a order with 3 products then I need to add an amount of 230€ to the total order cost. This amount is a flat amount (it will ever be 230€), it doesn't care how many products there are in the order.

I would use a Sales Taxes type tax but since it only accept percentages it is not useful for me.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to accomplish that using Rules.

Create a product that has the flat amount of 230€ and use the Rules action "Add product to the cart" to add that product to the cart.

To create the rule:

1. Create a Rule for event "After adding a product to the cart"
2. Add the "Order contains a particular product" condition to check if the
   order already has the flat amount product
3. Then add the "Add a product to a cart" to add the flat amount product to the order

You could add the same rule for the "After removing a product from the cart" event, so if they remove the flat rate product, it would just re-add it to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using pricing rule in drupal commerce.
Go to the admin/commerce/config/product-pricing, then create new pricing rule.
You can add event as per your requirement.Also you can add actions and conditions for your products.